# Cannot construct a collection

Tags: scala, collections

I have a `Stream` of data and I want to throw everything away except for the final *n* elements.  If the input doesn't have enough elements then the resulting stream is padded with `None`.  This is what I came up with:

```
def lastN[T](in: Stream[T], len: Int): Stream[Option[T]] =
  in.foldLeft(Vector.fill[Option[T]](len)(None))(_.tail :+ Option(_)).to[Stream]
```

I chose `Vector` for the internal buffer because of its `tail` and `append` [performance characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).

This all works fine.  Perhaps there's a better way? [Note: There's *always* a better way.]

But suppose `Iterator` is a more appropriate representation of the input data?  No problem, just replace the 3 mentions of `Stream` with `Iterator` and it all works.

OK, so why not either/both?

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
def lastN[T, C[U] <: TraversableOnce[U] ](in: C[T], len: Int): C[Option[T]] =
  in.foldLeft(Vector.fill[Option[T]](len)(None))(_.tail :+ Option(_)).to[C]
```

Alas, no go.

> error: Cannot construct a collection of type C[Option[T]] with
>   elements of type Option[T] based on a collection of type Nothing.

I've tried futzing with `CanBuildFrom` directly but I'm just not coming up with the magic formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more natural to use `Queue` as an internal buffer. It's more semantically suitable for this sort of processing and [`scala.collection.immutable.Queue`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.Queue) is implemented with two `List`s and may actually be more efficient than `Vector` (you'd have to make a measurement to find out if that's the case of course). Otherwise the API stays completely the same: you can just replace the mention of `Vector` with `Queue`.

As for `CanBuildFrom`, it's used in your code to call the `to` method. You can consult its full [signature](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike@to[Col[_]]:Col[A]) to find out what `CanBuildFrom` you'd have to request:

```
def to[Col[_]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, Col[A]]): Col[A]
```

So, you would need `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Option[T], C[Option[T]]]`.

Putting it all together a possible implementation looks like this:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue

def lastN[T, C[U] <: TraversableOnce[U]](in: C[T], len: Int)(
  implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Option[T], C[Option[T]]]
): C[Option[T]] =
  in.foldLeft(Queue.fill(len)(None: Option[T]))(_.tail :+ Option(_)).to[C]
```

---

As for your comment, the compiler knows that to call `to` it needs `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Option[T], C[Option[T]]]`, but it can't automatically find an implicit argument with abstract types.

But if you put a request `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Option[T], C[Option[T]]]` in the `lastN` signature, then when you call for example `lastN(Vector(1,2,3), 2)`, the compiler knows that `C` is `Vector`, and `T` is `Int`, so it has to pass a `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Option[Int], Vector[Option[Int]]]`.

Here all types are concrete and the compiler can find a relevant instance of `CanBuildFrom` using the usual [implicit lookup rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits). I believe, it will find one in the companion object of `Vector` in this example.

Comment: this shows no improvement over the original version (still fails compilation, with the same error).

Comment: Indeed, I am. Don't know what I was smoking :(
Please, edit your answer, so I can retract my downvote

Comment: @Kolmar, many thanks.  Exactly what I was looking for, but I can't say I completely understand it.  The compiler knows what needs to be built (see error text) but the implicit CanBuildFrom that `to` pulls down is insufficient (the signature looks good to me).  So if I pull in an implicit CanBuildFrom with the exact signature then `to` can use it?  Back to the books for me.

Comment: @jwvh Added a little explanation for your question. I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the last N elements of an `Iterable`, you can use the `takeRight` function. This should work for any collection that inherits from `Iterable`, so it will work for `Stream`. Unfortunately, it has been pointed out that this does not work for `Iterator`.

```
def lastN[T](in: Iterable[T], n: Int) = in.takeRight(n)
```

`Traversable`, the superclass of `Iterator`, does have a `toIterable` function you can use though. If you really want to make it as generic as possible, you can try:

```
def lastN[T](in: Traversable[T], n: Int) = in.toIterable.takeRight(n)
```

Comment: Beautifully simple and straight forward.  Unfortunately `Iterator` doesn't have the `takeRight` method.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I don't know why I thought `Iterator` inherited from `Iterable`.